# unable to understand work of unset() using indirect reference in PHP

Tags: php, unset

I am new to PHP and using version 5.6. I am trying to understand the functionality of unset() in case of using indirect reference.
unset() set the memory free used by the previous variable if no other variable reference to its value. In my code unset() works well and it returns false. But when I use indirect reference to variable, it still returns false.
Here is my code...

```
  //unsetting the variable
  $unset_var="darsh";
        //Indirect refernces to variables
        $$unset_var="new to PHP";
        echo "\n\n".$darsh;
  unset($unset_var);
  if(isset($unset_var))
  {
        print "<br>".'$unset_var variable is not free to use';
  }
  else 
  {
        print "<br>".'$unset_var variable is free to use';
  }
```

Comment: And what? Where's the indirect reference?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
$a = "x";
$$a = 'Value of $$a'; // creates a variable called $x
                      // because the literal value of $a = 'x'
                      // think about it as: ${$a}

echo $$a . "<br>";  // 'Value of $$a'
echo $x . "<br>";   // 'Value of $$a'

unset($a);

echo $a . "<br>";   // Notice: Undefined variable
echo $$a . "<br>";  // Notice: Undefined variable - because {$a} has been unset
echo $x . "<br>";   // 'Value of $$a' - $x has not been unset
```